# Using self developed Bada application for own smartphones

Tags: operating-system, licensing, smartphone, signing, bada

Hello Stackoverflow Community.

I'm doing some research about the most common operating Systems for Smartphones and the license (signing) conditions for developing .

At the moment i have some trouble with getting the needed informations about the Bada OS.

The Situation:

Let's say I have 10 Bada Smartphones and developed an App for them. Is it possible to install it directly on the phones (Like the apk File in Android)? If yes, are there any Restrictions like developer signing (36 month license / restricted access to System Resources, etc) ?

If this is not possible:

This would mean that the installation is only possible over the samsung store right ? I found some informations about this way on this site: http://developer.bada.com/support-publish . There was something mentioned about a certification process. Does any fees come up with this (like in symbian)?

I already used google a lot with all kinds of Keywords.
Perhaps I just missed the right word to search for.

It would be very nice if someone got some answers for me (in the best case with a resource that confirms the statements)

many thanks

Comment: Welcome around. If you found a satisfactory answer to your question, please mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark next to the answer - such is the StackOverflow way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after some more days of finding answers, this is my final summarize:

**First Way:**

- you have to create an account at developer.bada.com
- secondly you have to upload your app to your account and generate there an Manifest File
- finally you can download it on (max. 5) Devices (if you need more you have to generate a new Manifest => Repeat this process)
- they're no restrictions for the app (you can use it the whole time without functional restrictions like no access to the network)
- they're no fees coming up with this process (Registration/Upload/Download etc)

This way is just a short summarize. You have also to use the "Test Kit" which Peyman Irani noticed.
( http://developer.bada.com/article/Using-the-bada-Test-Kit )

**Second Way:**

- create an account at http://seller.samsungapps.com/main/sellerMain.as
- Upload the Application to the seller site.
- Now you can download that Application to all bada devices
- there no fees coming up with that (! As far as I know without testing it !)
- Once the App is uploaded, it is available for all other people (So this is probably not the best Solution for an App that is intended for private purpose )

Answer (score 0):

Application development process in bada SDK has two standard options for testing applications. The first one is the simulator and the second one is Target-device like your wave device, but now I am gonna tell you about [using the bada Test Kit](http://developer.bada.com/article/Using-the-bada-Test-Kit/).

In bada OS you can't move any application package directly to your phone storage unless you use spoofing or bada IDE 'Run as Target-release command' in project explorer right-click popup menu, but still you can just test one application ID so you can just test one version of an application. So what if you like to test earlier version of your application? The answer is the subject of this text 'bada Test Kit'.

In brief the steps are, you sign your developed application package through Samsung bada developers site "developer.bada.com" (shortly developers site) and then download it to your phone.

During this process you need a toll, you should install [TestKit application](http://www.samsungapps.com/topApps/topAppsDetail.as?productId=G00001930369) into your phone and then register your bada device Information with device ID provided by the TestKit in the developers site.

Remember that your developed application should be preconfigured in the developers site "My Applications" menu, then you should download the manifest.xml file and import it to your project, before building the package, for from now on steps check this: Make Test Kit Item "developer.bada.com/apis/myapp/testKit.do".

P.S: sorry for two broken links, because I am new here I could just send 2 links in my answers.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.
I read the article about the test kit.
So this means i have to register my app and then got the possibility to download it on my smartphones. I couldn't find anything about the toll you mentioned. Is this a constant fee? How much is it ?
About installation the IDE way. Does this mean i can install my app on all my devices through a connection with the IDE ? "Testing one version of my App". That means i can always install the latest version of my App on my phones ?  Thanks very much in advance !