# Understanding of QA and publishing process in samsung app store

Tags: bada

I'm developing an app for samsung bada.
Refer post: [Using self developed Bada application for own smartphones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879508/using-self-developed-bada-application-for-own-smartphones)

It tells:
- upload app to the seller site;
- now you can download it;

I have 2 questions here:

1) How much time does it take from second to third step?

2) Сan I avoid publishing my app in samsung app store?

I don't want it to be available for downloading by anybody, but regenerating manifest is not appropriate for me.

Comment: There's no app sideloading on bada - it's not Android. TestKit is for beta testing, not for general availability releases.

Answer (score 1):

1) Once the app is uploaded for certification, it usually takes 5 working days to be approved. Once approved it will normally take a further 1-2 working days before it appears in the app store for others to download.

2) As mentioned in the link you refer to above, you have the option to distribute your app using TestKit. This process is managed through the Bada developer site not the seller site so you should not upload to the seller site if you do not want it in the app store. There is an additional option to make your app go through certification and when it is ready to be published you can request to suspend the app in the seller site so it will not appear in the app store.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but using TestKit means upload application using IDE, isn't it? And what I want is give my users a link, so they will download and install my app by themselves.

Comment: TestKit uses the same app package file created from the IDE that is uploaded to the seller office. It's not possible as far as i know to provide a download link to a TestKit app. The users will need to download the TestKit app onto their phone and you will provide them an access code to enable download. Downloads through a link are only supported via the Samsung app store links on Bada.

Answer (score 0):

there's no link you can provide to install the application, your client should install the test kit application in his device, once the application is installed, it gives his device a unique id, you have to add this id in your component Setup of your in the bada developer account, once added, he will see the application in his applications list, and he can download it without passing by Samsung Apps, please refer to the link below, it gives all the details :)

http://developer.bada.com/article/Using-the-bada-Test-Kit

Best regards